# mongoDB: can't update

Tags: java, mongodb, database

I try update but returns my ObjectId = null!

```
try {
    //mongoCollection.update("{_id : #}", id).with("{$set: {nome: #}}", nome);
    System.out.println(mongoCollection.findOne("{_id : #}", id).as(BasicDBObject.class));
    mongoCollection.withWriteConcern(WriteConcern.SAFE).findAndModify(
           "{_id : #}", id).returnNew().with(
           "{$set : {'nome' : #}}", nome).as(BasicDBObject.class);

}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

PS: String id: `50ad6e30a54d7094b8d75315` and exists in db!

Comment: What version of the Java driver are you using? I don't see any `findOne` method that accepts a string in the latest version.

Comment: Now works \o The problem is " findAndModify("{_id : #}", id) ", id needs casting like: " "{'_id' : #}", new org.bson.types.ObjectId(id) "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try {
        //mongoCollection.update("{_id : #}", new org.bson.types.ObjectId(id)).with("{$set: {nome: #}}", nome);
        System.out.println(mongoCollection.findOne("{_id : #}", new org.bson.types.ObjectId(id)).as(BasicDBObject.class));
        mongoCollection.withWriteConcern(WriteConcern.SAFE).findAndModify(
               "{_id : #}", new org.bson.types.ObjectId(id)).returnNew().with(
               "{$set : {'nome' : #}}", nome).as(BasicDBObject.class);

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```